# How to show Date as Dynamic Parameter with Product Listing Date in PHP

Tags: php, date

We have a listing page wherein we show in current date of listing a product.

Code is:

```
<li><span>Listing Date</span></li>
<li><?php echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime($this->prodDet->adddate));?></li>
```

How to make date as dynamic parameter
so that it can have value basis current date comparison with listing date and show message as

i.e if present date is less than 1 month old - New Listing

i.e if present date is > 1 month but less than 180 days old -  More than a month Old

If listing date is > 180 days - Listing Expired

Comment: create a drop down with all your date range 

you can get a date back one month by

`$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify('-1 month');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');`

for more information see http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php

Comment: Thanks, but the example code only displays a date which is a month old from the present date, even the reference link is stating to show some other date. My question was different - as to know how to display a message wherein the listing date is compared with date on which the person is viewing the listing and basis that if its falling under 30 days should show as new listing, if more than that as another message and if > 180 days as expired listing !!

Comment: wr is the data in db then you can do it with query itself